# error while executing excel file in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have tried the following query in a SQL query

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 12.0;Database=c:\generalholiday.xls','select * from [sheet1$]')
```

The following error is happened:

> OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)"
>   returned message "The Microsoft Access database engine could not find
>   the object 'sheet1$'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell
>   its name and the path name correctly. If 'sheet1$' is not a local
>   object, check your network connection or contact the server
>   administrator.". Msg 7350, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 Cannot get the
>   column information from OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for
>   linked server "(null)".

Actually I searched lot of answered based on this queries. But I did not get reliable result for me.

What I have done so far,

I installed access database engine 64 bit, and run the following queries

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'ad hoc distributed queries', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'AllowInProcess', 1 
GO 
EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'DynamicParameters', 1 
GO
```

but still the above error is occurred. it is headache for me a full day to find this solution.

Please give me solution for this problem.

I am using SQL Server 2008 (64 bit) and MS Office 32 bit

Comment: Is there a sheet named sheet1?

Comment: Yes. Name Sheet1 is  in the excel sheet.

Comment: Are those case sensitive?  You have sheet1 above, not Sheet1, have you been able to query any Excel sheets on this server in the past?

Comment: Yes.I checked with case censitive.but still the error occur. I used this type of same sql server query  with my previous laptop(that is 32 bit processor). but this one windows 8 64 bit. and my ms office is 32 bit.

Answer (score 0):

I remember having similar errors setting this up initially on my server and I can't remember which bit solved it, but I believe it may have been running the following:

```
USE [master]
GO
EXEC master . dbo. sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' , N'AllowInProcess' , 1
GO
EXEC master . dbo. sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' , N'DynamicParameters' , 1
GO
```

Also, if I remember correctly the Excel file can't be open elsewhere when you try to query it.

Comment: I executed this stored procedure also.but still the problem is occured.